# When to run regression test suite vs full test suite for mobile apps?

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, regression-testing

I have some prior experience in regression test suite vs full automation suite testing, but when it comes to mobile apps, what are the best practices? For mobile apps. are the following correct?

- Smoke or BAT tests are needed when regression test suite takes a long time and developers need immediate feedback. Then smoke runs as part of every check-in?
- Regression test suite is the ideal one to run against every check-in but if takes long, it should run at least nightly? Should it be a fixed set or changed dynamically per release as per what you think needs to be "regressed"?
- Full suite should be run once prior to release, but in which environment - is it against dev or QA environments (or) against staging or pre-prod? If it is not suitable for staging or pre-prod, should I then run regression against stage or pre-prod?

How will above strategy change if some part of app has to be manually tested (either not automatable or work in progress)?

How does the above change for normal web projects?

Thanks.
Paddy

Answer (score 0):

Good question.
At first, i would recommend to look into these 2 blog posts which i wrote around mobile test automation - in general, i believe that the context of your tests should be derived from the most sensitive changes you are making to your mobile app. If e.g. you changed the Login area in your app - it is definitely relevant to assure that you 1st develop new tests (unit/functional) to cover these changes + execute
1) https://mobiletestingblog.com/2016/05/07/7-mobile-test-automation-best-practices/
2) https://mobiletestingblog.com/2016/02/11/tests-to-include-within-automation-suite/

If you have some kind of dashboard to show trending across latest mobile app builds where you see the added value from defect perspective to your existing test suite you should leverage this data as well

Hope that helps.